Langchain FastEmbed with ChromaDB
I'm trying to follow a simple example I found of using Langchain with FastEmbed and ChromaDB. I will eventually hook this up to an off-line model as well. I believe I have set up my python environment correctly and have the correct dependencies. Just am I doing something wrong with how I'm using the embeddings and then calling Chroma.from_documents?
from langchain_community.embeddings.fastembed import FastEmbedEmbeddings
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores.utils import filter_complex_metadata
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import glob

class ChatPDF:
    vector_store = None
    retriever = None
    chain = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.embeddings = FastEmbedEmbeddings()
        self.text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=100)

    def ingest(self, file_path: str):

        doc = PyPDFLoader(file_path=file_path).load()
        chunks = self.text_splitter.split_documents(doc)
        chunks = filter_complex_metadata(chunks)

        # generate vector store
        vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(documents=chunks, embedding=self.embeddings)




new_chat = ChatPDF()
docs_to_process = glob.glob("tmp/*.pdf")

for pdf in docs_to_process:
    new_chat.ingest(file_path=pdf)

When I run it however, I get the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/embeddings-test.py", line 35, in <module>
    new_chat.ingest(file_path=pdf)
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/embeddings-test.py", line 26, in ingest
    vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(documents=chunks, embedding=self.embeddings)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 878, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 842, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas, ids=ids)
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 277, in add_texts
    embeddings = self._embedding_function.embed_documents(texts)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/c/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/fastembed.py", line 117, in embed_documents
    embeddings = self._model.embed(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'embed'


I'm trying right now to rerun a code that works previously on Google Colab, but without success.
It looks like the current version (0.3.0) of langchain and/or langchain-community isn't working with FastEmbed. Downgrading to langchain==0.2.14 and langchain-community==0.2.12 works as expected.

This is a documented issue in the langchain-ai Github repository (https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain). It seems to be related to a failed initialization of the model from the fastembed library due to a pydantic typing mismatch.
There is a working patch listed there while the fix is deployed (https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/26631).
Patch (thanks to Github user andreabellacicca) :
from langchain_community.embeddings.fastembed import FastEmbedEmbeddings
from fastembed import TextEmbedding

emb_model = FastEmbedEmbeddings(model_name="Qdrant/clip-ViT-B-32-text")
text_emb = TextEmbedding(model_name="Qdrant/clip-ViT-B-32-text")
emb_model._model = text_emb
vector_store = Chroma(collection_name="my_collection",
                                             embedding_function=emb_model
)

